# Why does my tensorboard say: 'No scalar data was found' when using SummaryWriter.add_scalar?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard

I am attempting to visualize a loss vs. epoch graph using tensorboard (by calling .addscalar()) so that I can appropriately tune my neural network model. However, after training the model, I check my tensorboard in the web browser and it reads: 'No scalar data was found.'

I've tried checking my events statistics and it seems like there are scalars:

```
Event statistics for runs/tf_druggability/classification_ffnn_1:
audio -
graph -
histograms -
images -
scalars
   first_step           0
   last_step            90
   max_step             90
   min_step             0
   num_steps            10
   outoforder_steps     [(90L, 0L), (90L, 0L)]
sessionlog:checkpoint -
sessionlog:start -
sessionlog:stop -
tensor -
```

Here's my code:

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

sess = tensorflow.Session()
writer = SummaryWriter('runs/tf_druggability/classification_ffnn_1', sess.graph)

for epoch in range(100):

    # Wrap input data and labels in Variable to can gradient descent (in place of DataLoader)
    inputs = Variable(traindf_to_tensor)
    labels = Variable(trainlabels_to_tensor)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = net(inputs)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if(epoch%10 == 0):

        # HERE I WRITE to the LOG FILE for TENSORBOARD:
        writer.add_scalar('training loss', loss.item(), epoch)
        print('epoch {}, loss {}'.format(epoch, loss.item()))

writer.close()
print('Finished training! :)')
```

When I try to open the events file in Jupyter Notebooks it has this in it (... means I've omitted the middle part):

```
1800 0000 0000 0000 a37f 4b22 09f2 3d6b
a51e 58d7 411a 0d62 7261 696e 2e45 7665
6e74 3a32 ac51 0a16 2100 0000 0000 0000
...
f723 0000 0000 0000 00b0 9f77 4309 d00a
0ea7 1e58 d741 105a 2a16 0a14 0a0d 7472
6169 6e69 6e67 5f6c 6f73 7315 c193 403f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the graphs only displayed if I was in the exact **same** directory as the program I'm running. Being in a higher directory than that of the program seems to have caused this inability to display graphs.

Comment: By passing `'runs/tf_druggability/classification_ffnn_1'` as path you are specifiying a relative path. That's why you need to be in the dir where `runs` is available. You can be in any dir if you specifiy the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you passing a tensorflow `session.graph` object to a Pytorch `SummaryWriter()` object. [Here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html) you can find some basic example of using tensorboard to write graphs and scalars etc.

Comment: In a different attempt, I omitted the session.graph object, and that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: You can try using [TensorboardX](https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboardX) and see if it works. It provides a very similar API.